# Storing Google App Permissions - iOS

Tags: ios, google-authentication

I'm new to iOS development/Objective C so please be gentle ;-)

I am creating an app that uses the Google+ Sign-In SDK and I have a working prototype where the user taps the google sign-in button, they are then re-directed to safari where they log into their Google account and are finally presented with the Account Permissions screen for my App, before returning back to the iOS app.

The issue I have is that after allowing the app to access the relevant information, the user is constantly navigated to the Account Permissions screen when logging into the app through Google Sign In.

Now, I was under the impression that once a user has allowed the app to access the relevant information then users won't be asked to approve this unless they have revoked access through security.google.com but I am finding that I am always having to approve permissions after each login attempt.

Has anyone had this issue before?  I've performed a few google searches to look for the answer to this issue but haven't had much luck.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks.

Code below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
    signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = YES; // get the user profile
    signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;  // get the user's email
    signIn.scopes = @[ @"profile" ];            // "profile" scope

    // Optional: declare signIn.actions, see "app activities"
    signIn.delegate = self;

    [signIn trySilentAuthentication];

}

- (void)finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth error:(NSError *)error {

        GTLQueryPlus *query = [GTLQueryPlus queryForPeopleGetWithUserId:@"me"];

        // 1. Create a |GTLServicePlus| instance to send a request to Google+.
        GTLServicePlus* plusService = [[GTLServicePlus alloc] init] ;
        plusService.retryEnabled = YES;

        // 2. Set a valid |GTMOAuth2Authentication| object as the authorizer.
        [plusService setAuthorizer:[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].authentication];

        // 3. Use the "v1" version of the Google+ API.*
        plusService.apiVersion = @"v1";
        [plusService executeQuery:query
                completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                    GTLPlusPerson *person,
                                    NSError *error)
         {

            if (error) {

                NSLog(@"Received Error %@ and auth object==%@", error, auth);

            }

            else {
                // Send the basic user information to the console
                NSLog(@"Email=%@", [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].authentication.userEmail);
                NSLog(@"User Name=%@", [person.name.givenName stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@", person.name.familyName]);
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginSuccessful" sender:self]; // Once logged in send user to main view
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `trySilentAuthentication` which is part of the google sign in SDK. You can find out who to use it here: http://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick response.  I am using this in the viewDidLoad method of the login view controller, unless this is the incorrect place?

Comment: No that's the right place. Can you share your code?

Comment: Ok, I've added the code for the two methods that handle the login functionality.